# Inserting Data Into Db By Entity Framework Throwing Errors

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework

I Trying to insert the data into Database By using entity framework but it throwing error following 
An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Code is Here

```
public int InsertUserData(UserDetail userDetail, BusinessObjects objects)
    {
        try
        {
            UserCredential objCredentials = newPersonEntity.UserCredentials
            .First(cd => cd.UserName == objects.UserName);
            objCredentials.Status = objects.Status;
            newPersonEntity.UserDetails.Add(userDetail);
            int result=newPersonEntity.SaveChanges();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {  
            CatchError(ex);
            return 3;
        }


    }
```

Can Any One Tell what mistake i did ?

Comment: What is the inner exception? Probably a foreign key issue.

Comment: @JRLambert Already Foreign key value available in Primary key Table

Comment: Ok, but what does the inner exception say?

Comment: ThankYou For response guys I used One column as  primary key which is the inner exception i solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i undestand your code snipped correctly, you don't need to perform operations with objCredentials. Or if you want to change its status, you must call

```
newPersonEntity.UpdateObject(objCredentials);
```

And the only reason, why you cannot save changes is incorrect userDetail object fields values. Check that all required fields filled correclty and don't conflict with existing key values, stored in dataBase